# Access hidden property from child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Sometimes in C# it is useful to hide properties of an inherited base class, such as when you want to change the type. However, once I have hidden the inherited property, I don't know how to read or write the value of the hidden property.

Here's a small example using Animals and Dogs:

```
public enum DogBreed {
    Corgi, Pug
}
public class Animal {
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}
public class Dog : Animal {
    public new DogBreed? Breed {
        get {
            // Not working since "Breed" now refers to Dog.Breed not Animal.Breed
            if (Breed == "Corgi") return DogBreed.Corgi;
            if (Breed == "Pug") return DogBreed.Pug;
            return null;
        }
        set {
            // Also Not working for same reason as above
            if (value == DogBreed.Corgi) Breed = "Corgi";
            else if (value == DogBreed.Pug) Breed = "Pug";
            else Breed = null;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access the hidden property? (Animal.Breed)

Comment: 1) The syntax you're looking for is `base.Breed`.  2) Personally, I would declare `enum DogBreed { Corgi, Pug}` *INSIDE* of "Animal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `base` keyword:

```
public class Dog : Animal {
    public new DogBreed? Breed {
        get {
            // base.Breed refers to the hidden property
            if (base.Breed == "Corgi") return DogBreed.Corgi;
            if (base.Breed == "Pug") return DogBreed.Pug;
            return null;
        }
        set {
            if (value == DogBreed.Corgi) base.Breed = "Corgi";
            else if (value == DogBreed.Pug) base.Breed = "Pug";
            else base.Breed = null;
        }
    }
}
```